# How to automatically populate the Phone & Home Phone on MobilePhone Updates?

Tags: apex, workflow

I am new to the `salesforce` and have the query, In Account, I have a Mobile (`FieldName` : `MobilePhone`), once this Mobile field is populated, I want to auto populate the `Phone & Home Phone` both.

Thing is that I am going to upload 1L of accounts using data loader, in that case also I want to auto-populate the Phone & Home Phone` both.

What approach/OOB features do I need to take ?

I want all highlighted part to be updated automatically.

[image]

Comment: What happens if Phone and home phone have the values? do you want to overwrite those values with MobilePhone?

Comment: Secondly, account doesn't have all the fields though Contact has. Are those fields are custom fields?

Comment: If Phone and home phone has the values, you don't need to do anything. If Phone and home phone don't have any values & only Phone has values then auto-populate Phone and home phone. No these are the standard fields only.

Comment: Are you using Person Accounts?

Comment: yes Santanu, I am happy that you shown using Contact!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update those values using Process Builder.

Though in the below example I have shown you Object as Contact, since Contact object has MobilePhone, HomePhone and Phone attributes (Standard).

**Criteria**

[image: Mobile Phone exists]

**Immediate Actions**

Action Type as Update Record and define the logic as below.

[image: update contact phone]

By the way, Account only has Phone attribute. HomePhone and MobilePhone does not exist as Standard Attributes of Account (Business). Person Account has those fields.

You just choose the Object as Account and define the criteria and actions as shown in the picture, it will work as expected.

Comment: yes, update record as action type

Comment: Thank you, please see updates above, but same I want to update into the Phone field as well if Phone is not already populated/present, then populate it with the MobilePhone value

Comment: Then add an update action for Phone as well