# Unable to autopopulate Home Phone and Phone on Mobile value creatred/updated

Tags: workflow, process-builder

Creating new question from the link [How to automatically populate the Phone & Home Phone on MobilePhone Updates?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176488/how-to-automatically-populate-the-phone-home-phone-on-mobilephone-updates) , as I want to update both Home Phone and Phone on the Mobile Phone update value on the below conditions:

1) If Phone & Home Phone value is already populated, then dont update anything.

2) If Phone & Home Phone value is not present and Mobile value is present, then auto-populate same values. There is 100% Mobile value always need to populate while creating account.

[image]

Based on Suggestions from Santanu, I created below, but Phone and Home Phone value is not populating. Why ?

**Contact**

[image]

**Define Criteria for Action Groups**

[image]

**Update Records**

[image]

==============================================================================

**My Updated Screen shots:**

[image]

**Define Criteria for this Action Group**

[image]

**Update Records**

[image]

**Update Records**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be single criteria, MobilePhone is not null.

[image: MobilePhone is not null]

> Create 2 separate separate actions.

1. One for Update Home Phone, where you will check is HomePhone is null, then update HomePhone taking reference from MobilePhone.

[image: update home phone]

2. Second one for Update BusinessPhone where you will check BusinessPhone is null then update BusinessPhone taking reference from MobilePhone.

[image: update business phone]

Do not club, both the actions into single action.

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: Do not change Mobile Phone exists criteria

Comment: In the Mobile Phone exists, you should check Mobile Phone value. Here you should not check HomePhone values

Comment: I have given the screenshot, pls check updated ans

Comment: Hey I double checked, its exactly the same like yours, but not working yet.